# Hg pull / clone

Tags: mercurial

I have a situation where I'm writing for a system that handles lots of repository, configuration, build and running stuff. There's a task which might as well be called `sync-repository` which the user should be able to call to ensure that the latest version of the repository gets to the client.

It's possible that the repo is already present, in which case I'd like to do a `hg update`. It's also possible that the repo isn't present, in which case I'd like to do a `hg clone`. The user shouldn't have to care which is the case. Oh, and the repository is big, so just wiping the directory and `clone`ing every time isn't an option.

Does `hg` provide a single command that `clone`s or `update`s under the hood, depending on which is appropriate? Or am I going to have to do it with bash?

Comment: Thanks for the find, I couldn't find that searching. I'm not sure it is a duplicate -- that question explains how to do it with bash, it doesn't answer whether or not there's a way to do it without bash (though the OP does ask that).

Comment: The lack of an answer saying how to do it in mercurial in the link above should be a hint that the easiest way is going to be in Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The user shouldn't have to care which is the case.

Yes, but **YOU must care and know**, does you  have clone or no. How you want to manage it?

If you have someconfig-file in form, f.e

Reponame = /full/path/to/clone

you can detect, if clone exist or not and use if-then-else logic. If you haven't information, you can't make decision

**Add-on**

No, the are not such "combined" command in Mercurial core (I hope, they never appear in it), because Mercurial doesn't go git-way "one command for different unrelated tasks" and follow Unix-way ("Mind your own business!") more strictly

But, from other side, it give you freedom do what you want - you can define own Mercurial commands (if you asked this), which may be a hodgepodge of unrelated original commands (see [Aliases extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AliasExtension) (wiki page is slightly outdated) and [[alias] section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) in .hgrc - up to date) and even use shell commands in Mercurial aliases

Comment: Well exactly, that's sort of the whole point of the question: do I have to care? I'm asking whether there's a Mercurial command for it, a question which I don't think you're answering. And I'm fine with finding workarounds, but I'd much rather use a Mercurial command (less hackiness ==  better).

Comment: @Hbcdev - "do I have to care?" you *can* care, or not: "it depends..." With bash you get **fast, cheap, not portable** solution, your logic will give **more expensive, not so fast, portable** solution. It's your decision what to choose

Comment: Are you saying that there _is_ a mercurial internal command for doing this but that it is somehow slower than using bash? I doubt that to be true.

Comment: @Hbcdev - see my edits in answer, I hope *they will answer*